# Sending 8-bit data serially

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to send parallel 8-bit data serially. When `Send` is 1, it should start sending data. It is shown in the below figure. [image]

```
module transmitter(Clk, Send, PDin, SCout, SDout);
input Clk, Send;
input [7:0] PDin;
wire reg [7:0] PD;

assign PD[7:0]= PDin[7:0];

output SCout;
output reg SDout;

always@(posedge Clk)
    PD[7:1] <= PD[6:0];

assign SCout = Clk;

always@(posedge SCout)
    if(Send== 1'b1)
       SDout <= 1'b1;
    else
       SDout <= PDin[7];

endmodule
```

Here,

```
wire reg [7:0] PD;
```

it throws error.

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at transmitter.v(4) near text
>   "reg";  expecting an identifier ("reg" is a reserved keyword ), or
>   "[", or "signed", or "unsigned"

I didn't use `PD` and had shifted `PDin` in always block before, however, it said `PDin` cannot be both input and reg. Therefore, I've updated the code as in the above.

Comment: `wire reg [7:0] PD;` You can't have a signal that is both a `wire` and a `reg`. In case you are wondering how to find that, I looked at line (4) for text reading `reg`, as stated by the error message - it's telling you that `reg` is unexpected (a.k.a. not allowed) at that point.

Comment: `assign PD[7:0]= PDin[7:0];` You can't assign a `reg` using an `assign` statement.

Comment: For readability, all of your `if`, `else`, and `always` statements should have `begin` and `end`. Just like in C where you have `{` and `}`.

Comment: If you want to perform some action (e.g. sending data bits) on and event (e.g. a signal going high), built a state machine.

Comment: For Asynchronous serial communication Start = "0 and "hi for RS-232

Comment: @dim done. It was my intention, but I didn't have time earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets look at the error message.

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at transmitter.v **(4)** near text **"reg"**; **expecting an identifier** ("reg" is a reserved keyword ), or "[", or "signed", or "unsigned"

On or near line 4 there is an error - near to a bit of text that reads "reg".

On line 4 we have `wire reg [7:0] PD;` - I spot the text "reg".

After the wire keyword, you must either give an identifier (the name of a wire), or a `[` (in case of a multi-bit wire), or specify whether the wire is `signed` or `unsigned` (default). Instead you have used a reserved keyword `reg`.

You can't have a signal that is both a wire and a reg.

---

Next, assuming you intend `PD` to be a `reg`, the line `assign PD[7:0]= PDin[7:0];` is also an error - you can't assign a reg using an assign statement. If you intended `PD` to be a `wire`, then you can't use it in the `always` block later on.

> I didn't use `PD`

Yes you did, you used it as the target of both a procedural assignment, and a continuous assignment. So you did use it. And in a way that is not allowed (see above).

---

As a third point, for readability, all of your `if`, `else`, and `always` statements should have a `begin` and an `end` keyword. You use `begin`/`end` in the same way you would use `{`/`}` in C. It might seem tedious, but it is good practice and will save you time in the long run.

---

As a final point, if you want to perform some action (e.g. sending data bits) on and event (e.g. a signal going high), you should look into building a state machine to control the flow. Remember that everything you are describing with Verilog is hardware (hence HDL), so if you want to perform a sequence of actions, you need a hardware construct which does that - a state machine is one example.